# In RStudio, `knit` always works, but `rmarkdown::render` fails on second run (but not first!)

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable, kableextra

I'm trying to do something quite simple: generate reports in PDF format. Finally found a way that reproduces my issue. I need to use `rmarkdown::render` to create reports based on data in `GlobalEnv`. I am using the `tinytex` package. Here is `test.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
mtcars %>%
  kable(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")
```
````

### Works:

"Knit" in RStudio seems to always work on this file, producing, as expected, the `mtcars` dataframe, nicely formatted with `kable()`

### Doesn't work (but should?):

Running `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` works on THE FIRST RUN, but NOT the second. It throws the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

After this, "Knit" in RStudio produces the PDF, but R/knitr prints any warning/error messages from the `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` command.

## Additional Information

Running `rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")` does not produce errors if the above code chunk is changed to

````
```{r cars}
mtcars %>%
  kable()
```
````

Answer (score 5):

That didn't work for me. I was getting a clash in xcolor option. The solution as pointed out in page 3 : https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

is to add :

```
options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
```

and in the YAML :

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
```

Note that you can remove any packages that you don't need.

Answer (score 3):

I've elected to answer my own question because I've found a work-around that hopefully will not be necessary if someone finds the reason for the errors.

It seems that the PDF rendering engine does not recognize anything but the most basic LaTeX installation of `tinytex`. I tried `tinytex::tlmgr_install` to manually install the necessary LaTeX packages but all of them returned a "package already present" message.

### Solution

I've added the following to my YAML in my Rmd:

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{booktabs}
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \usepackage{colortbl}
   - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

I essentially added each `\usepackage` line until I received no errors with the formatting I was looking for.

### Working Rmd code

Both `rmarkdown::render()` and `knit` (Rstudio) work (and on my OWN code as well!):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{booktabs}
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \usepackage{colortbl}
   - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
mtcars %>%
  kable(booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped")
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Using Rscript_call solved the problem for me in such cases.

```
library(rmarkdown)

# doesn't work on second run
render(input = "K:/file.Rmd")

# works on second run
xfun::Rscript_call(
  rmarkdown::render,
  list(input = 'K:/file.Rmd')
)
```